# Cortex-M0 vs. Cortex-M0+ for an IoT sensor using LoRA

Tags: arm, breakout, cortex-m0, cortex-m0+

Although I am an experienced software engineer, I am still quite a novice in electrical engineering.  So please bare with me in explaining my requirements:

I have a small garden in my backyard and I would like to add a soil moisture sensor in the ground, connecting it with an [RFM95W](https://www.ebay.com/i/181442612615?chn=ps) as a LoRaWAN node.

The sensor will likely take a measurement every 6 to 9 hours, and go to sleep to save battery life.

Whichever board I use will connect to another RFM95W that's a LoraWAN gateway hooked up to an Rpi inside my home, so that I can forward the data to a local LoRa Server (MQTT).

Eventually I hope to get to a point where the board will open a water source when the soil is dry (over PWM motor control -- which I have done with the Pi over bare metal before).

Secondly I hope to run some very basic deep learning on the data, directly on the MCU as discussed in [this blog post](https://deref-gmx.com/mail/client/Aaa1nRAWB4g/dereferrer/?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fpetewarden.com%2F2018%2F06%2F11%2Fwhy-the-future-of-machine-learning-is-tiny%2F)

Therefore, choosing an ARM MCU seems like a good fit.  There's the Cortex-M0 and its successor [the M0+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Cortex-M0+).

The problem I have in making the decision between them is based on the following:

1) The M0+ is marketed as a very power efficient MCU and therefore can work well with a battery for a long time

2) The M0 however seems to be very reasonably priced in its development boards, such as the [SMT32F](https://www.ebay.com/i/182448413897?chn=ps) vs. the [SAMD](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Adafruit/3657?qs=W0yvOO0ixfFjAZCEe%252bYvTg%3D%3D&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_4q3_47X2wIVDBgMCh2FNQeeEAkYBiABEgK8sPD_BwE)

Therefore I am wondering if the low power consumption is the case for the difference in price and if I can still get the same performance; i.e. long battery life, from the `M0`?

Comment: Could you, please, draw a picture to illustrate your setup? Because from description it seems you have more nodes than necessary. Also, what your home WiFI has to do with distance to your yard if you are using LoRa anyway?

Comment: If you are using ARM to read sensor and send data via LoRa then just about any MCU will do. For this task power consumption in sleep mode is defining factor and I believe you can find cheaper and better performing MCU, e.g. Attiny at 0.1uA (vs Cortex+ at 0.27uA)

Comment: @Maple I was using the WiFi range as reason why WiFi will not work, and I **have to** use LoRa.

Comment: @Maple to second point, I also want to do some deep learning on these IoT nodes.  Check out this blog post https://petewarden.com/2018/06/11/why-the-future-of-machine-learning-is-tiny/

Comment: Ah, OK, as a reason for using LoRa WiFi range makes sense. It is also information absolutely irrelevant to the question. I still don't get what you are using ARM for, if you connect sensor directly to LoRa, and another LoRa is on Rpi.

Comment: @Maple an ATtiny will not be up to the task of running a practically suitable radio stack for this transceiver, nor will that now ancient core necessarily win on power.  LoRa is a radio modulation, it is not a controller, so you cannot connect a sensor directly to it.  The Semtech LoRa chip in the mentioned Hope RF RFM95 is an SPI peripheral and needs quite a lot of support code from a host MCU for the typical protocols and frequency hopping schemes utilized with that modulation type.

Comment: @SamHammamy this type of question is off topic here.  The reality is you'll probably change course a few times before you have something deployed with useful battery life after you consider things like the regulator and receive windows (if you want downstream control, which is much more power expensive than upstream reporting).  Start with a higher memory resources ARM board for which you can find a good LoRa (or better, LoRaWAN or TTN) example, and once you've learned from that you can port to something that based on that experience feels like a better fit.

Comment: @Chris I imagine you say it is off-topic because you consider it is a shopping question. In my opinion, it is not. I read it as a "which of these devices fit my needs?" question. So, purely a design question. Would you consider a question such as "do I need a 330uF or a 1000uF capacitor" a shopping question? Now, there is however a bigger problem with this post as there is no clearly formulated actual question.

Comment: @dim - if someone posts a link to sales pages for two capacitors in lieu of listing the relevant specifications, it's probably going to be closed as a shopping question.  *Especially* if they don't give much specific basis for determining their actual need.

Comment: @ChrisStratton While I agree with your comment about learning from the experience, I have also been bitten by rushing to buy something only to find out it isn't exactly suitable for what I am trying to do, and it just ends up sitting wasted and unused.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: "so you cannot connect a sensor directly to it". OP: "add a soil moisture sensor in the ground, connecting it with an RFM95W". That is why I asked twice already for a picture or explanation how ARM will be used. I admit, I never worked with LoRa before but I can read, a little bit. And when I am reading RFM95 documentation I can see that it's not a "radio modulation". Data FIFO and some configuration registers over SPI too much for ATtiny? FHSS is only used when packets too long. How much data do you think moisture sensor generates?

Comment: @Maple - LoRa is a modulation. An RFM95 is a chip. However, it is typically used on a frequency band where hopping is effectively a regulatory requirement. A full node implementation of the schemes traditionally used in practice gets fairly complicated and takes no small amount of memory. In terms of wondering how the MCU is to be used, sorry, but that has to be considered as obvious to anyone meaningfully prepared to respond to the question. If someone doesn't understand that an MCU is obviously required here, then they are someone who does not have the perspective to usefully answer.

Comment: Personally, I'd get either the NUCLEO-L073RZ and prototype on a high memory variant until I made up my mind what I needed in deployment, or the CMWX1ZZABZ-078 which is the same 192KB M0+ combined with the SX1276 off the RFM95, in a compact module.

Comment: ARM does not make MCU cores.  ARM makes processor cores that chip vendors purchase along with other IP to put in their chips.  It is not in any way relevant to your task.  There is a vast array of MCUs with various processor cores (some purchased some vendors own IP) that can all do basic MCU tasks.

Comment: You have several tasks, first take ANY board, an rpi or whatever and figure out how to configure and use the RFM95W, most of that knowledge can be ported to your final platform.  Next do the low power work, most of the MCU vendors have low power products, buy one/some and figure out how to make them run at low power.  Also you have to do your power design, understand how much each component uses when sleeping and when not, is this solar, battery, etc.  And do that design.  it is great to have an overall goal but you have a long road to get there.

Comment: Expect failure and redesign.  if you stick with it you can on each new design extend the battery life or increase the range of your transmission, use a smaller battery, smaller enclosure, etc...

Comment: @old_timer I appreciate your feedback as always! I do realize that ARM only designs the cores and sells the ISA and core / bus design to manufacturers.  I am fairly confident that getting the Rpi and RFM95W communicating; while not trivial, is not terribly difficult for me now.  Especially having worked through your bare metal examples for the Rpi zero's for several months.  Plus writing a small kernel for PWM motor control, ADC sensor read ins.

Comment: @old_timer In working through those things, I made many mistakes; as expected, and one lesson learned is to not buy anything unless I am conceptually certain of how I will use it, program it, and so on.  The past 7 days have been spent in researching many different things; I was just reading your README on J-Tag last night for example. I am saying all this to clarify that I want to get something concrete and on paper before purchasing anything.  Since I posted this for example, I have been looking on mouser and reading the user manuals for several other development boards.

Comment: @old_timer Case in point is the 81-CMWX1ZZABZ-078 recommended by Chris Stratton.  Had I bought the RFM95W, and later found out about this, I most likely would have bought this also. But I also learned that listening to your advice is always the right thing to do! So I will focus on that piece of it firstly, and come back to the sensor piece!  As always, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible to answer this question accurately, because neither you nor the article you link to provide any sort of useful definition of 'deep learning'. Depending on who you talk to, this can encompass simple filtering and correlation work, all the way up to what DeepMind are doing. The term is ambigiuous to the point of being meaningless.

At a more practical level, there are very few differences between the M0 and M0+. While the M0+ has the potential to be more power efficient, the reality is that it depends much more heavily on the actual vendor implementation. On a very low power system peripherals and clock circuits can easy negate any power savings in the core itself. Most vendors have specific ranges of chips that are optimised for power saving, and you should just make your decision based on the characteristics of these chips - ignoring whether the internal implementation is an M0/M0+ or even any other Cortex M core.

One thing to note is that the M0/M0+ architecture is quite badly IO constrained, as it typically takes 2-3 instruction cycles to load/store a register from memory or IO. There is also no load/store pipelining as in the higher end Cortex chips. The result is that if you are doing a lot of bit bashing then an 8-bit processor can usually run rings around an M0/M0+. For example, flipping an IO port bit on the PIC12 can be done in 1 instruction cycle. On a Cortex M0/M0+ it would take between 5 and 7.

At the other end of the performance spectrum, this slowness of register transfers can also have a profound impact on the chip's ability to process large data sets (e.g. if you are implementing a filter or correlator). Going to something more powerful like an M3/M4 might actually gain you power efficiency under heavy math loads but you'd need to know a lot more about what analysis you plan to do before you could determine that.

Comment: Not at all true! DeepLearning has a clear definition: injecting one or more layers of a neural network into any machine learning task. Taking in the output of an SVM for example, or used as output to a reinforcement learning algorithm.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it really gives an excellent reasoning for why the question is too vague.  I have a lot to get to before I can decide how the learning will work.